# Programmatically delete a row from a CSV file after 24 hours are elapsed

Tags: c++, csv, timestamp, delete-row, c++-chrono

So, I am trying to add a user entry with a timestamp in a CSV in C++.

The CSV looks like this:

| NAME | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| DULQUERSALMAN | 12:00:00 |

And I need to delete this `DULQUERSALMAN` entry after 24 hrs from the CSV. How can I do this?

This is the code I currently have, which adds the row above including the timestamp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("Data.csv", ios::out | ios::app);
    cout << "Enter the name:";
    cin >> name;

    auto givemetime = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
   
    myfile <<  name << ";" << ctime(&givemetime);
}
```

Now I need to delete the entry when it gets older than 24 hours. How can I do this?

Comment: are you asking how to sleep your program for 24 hours?

Comment: Hi
463035818_is_not_a_number, No I need to delete a entry in CSV after 24hrs...could you help me with that ??

Comment: what should your program do during that 24 hours?

Comment: Do you want to remove all the entries that are older than 24 hours? Or does your program need to run for 24 straight hours and then delete the same entry you added. It's unclear. You should make it clearer. Please edit your post.

Comment: How do you know how many hours have passed with this kind of truncated timestamp???

Comment: **aside:** it's a lot easier to generate a new, modified, file than editing a file in-place.